# Xcode: Adding Existing Files to Groups & Files Pane causes build error

Tags: xcode

I'm working on a project hosted in Beanstalk and would like to access one of my files in my subversion repository.

I can clearly see the files "SoundEffect.h" and "SoundEffect.m" in the web-based browser directory, but the files do not appear in the "Groups and Files" pane on the left of Xcode after a refresh and update from Xcode.

I tried to "right click on a file, and add->existing files" for both SoundEffect.(h|m) and they both appear. But now my project won't build and I get strange errors like

"_AudioServicesPlaySystemSound", referenced from:
"_AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID", referenced from:
"_AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID", referenced from:

even though I haven't used the files. I'm pretty sure the files are free of error because I have used them successfully in another project.

What is going on and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683940/referencing-error-to-the-audiotoolbox-in-objective-c) that helped.

I needed to add the Framework AudioToolbox.Framework in XCode.